# Send notification to specific user android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

How can I send a notification from one user to another using Android (I'm using firebase database).

I have a student user when he clicks on a button it will send a notification to his Academic advisor.

I've watched a lot of tutorials but all of them are using notificationCompat and noificationManager and I can't specify to which user this notification will be send

Thanks

Comment: do you want to send notification using token

Comment: do you have auth key..

Comment: You can create tag for the each user ..For that user from your server side you need send notification  based on the user tag

Comment: @EnamulHaque So , can't I send notification based on userID? If I can't I will use token but I don't know exactly how :(

Comment: Check bellow code....

Answer (score 1):

You can send notification using token..You can get token..

1. Create android project in android studio
2. Open the project & Go to >Tools>Firebase>cloud messaging>set up firebase cloud messaging>
3. connection to your apps firebase>Connect to firebase>Create a new project using email
4. Add FCM to your app
5. Note: You need to a gmail address for adding above 3 & 4 . These will automatically configure your gadle don't do anything...
6. Create a class named FirebaseIDService & paste bellow code ..

   ```
    public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
     public void onTokenRefresh() {
           String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Log.e("***refreshedToken",refreshedToken);


       }

    }
   ```
7. In Manifest file you add

   ```
   <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService" android:exported="true">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </service>
   ```
8. You will get a toke like bellow error log

   ***refreshedToken: eroNxVsruNk:APA91bF5gSK4Hlt-x-Pc2ecw0D8vMHoXwdZ-JY9SSl4KNLV_wUjA76T0Icv6Cxgf8pX9eDPMT3i3UhdxY27CxcvvKX5p6wHEBaX36wvE3kGapTI3uytUCQuBfh56Ss0y419kmBklew-7
9. Now you will send message using this token.. to the specific device because this token generated for installing apps  that means if you install this app yow will get a unique token & if your friend install same app your friend will get the toke. so you will get another unique token and preserved it .. & though these tokens you can send the message...i think will work..